# How to save immediately dockers images created in multi-stage docker?

Tags: docker, travis-ci

I want to cache my docker on travis. The best method would be just saving newly created image on disk with *docker save*.

It would be super simple with a classic one-image-docker build, but I need to have a small final image, so I do multi-stage:

```
FROM danlynn/ember-cli:3.0.0 AS deps

RUN mkdir -p /client

# get nodejs deps:
COPY client/package.json /client/
COPY client/package-lock.json /client/

WORKDIR /client

RUN npm install node-sass
RUN npm install
RUN npm rebuild node-sass
... more long operations

FROM node:wheezy AS server
COPY --from=deps /client/ /client/
```

Is there a way to save immediately image *deps* and restore it later?

Comment: Can you explain why you're looking to do that? Maybe there's another option

Answer (score 3):

You can build a specific stage with `docker build --target`, so you don't need to build all stages all the time. I think this should be helpful in your case.

You can read about this in Docker docs here: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#stop-at-a-specific-build-stage.

> When you build your image, you don’t necessarily need to build the entire Dockerfile including every stage. You can specify a target build stage. The following command assumes you are using the previous Dockerfile but stops at the stage named builder:
>   Blockquote

`$ docker build --target builder -t alexellis2/href-counter:latest .`

You can even use an external image as a stage, it is described in the same docs, so you can do something like this:

`COPY --from=nginx:latest /etc/nginx/nginx.conf /nginx.conf`